# Access method from different package in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to automate android game. I have so many methods so I break my code in 3 parts.
**main**, **functions** and **collectors**.
I have a method in **functions** which is:

```
def search_image(image, confidence=.6, click=True):
location = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(image, confidence=confidence)
if location is not None:
    if click:
        pyautogui.click(location)
    return location
else:
    return False
```

But I cant access it in **collectors**, like this:

```
from functions import*
def collect_product():
    if search_image(r'Resources\NewOrderAvailable.png') is not False:
        search_image(r'Resources\NewOrderAvailable2.png')
        for item in range(0, 6):
            search_image(r'Resources\Collect.png', confidence=.8)
        search_image(r'Resources\Back.png')
        search_image(r'Resources\CloseOrderMenu.png')
    else:
        return False
```

I got ***NameError: name 'search_image' is not defined***. I need to duplicate that method to make it work. I was wondering what went wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is not an instance of the class. You need to add a [self](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/self-in-python-class/#:~:text=self%20represents%20the%20instance%20of,attributes%20with%20the%20given%20arguments.&text=self%20is%20parameter%20in%20function,name%20in%20place%20of%20it.) keyword to make it accessible outside.

```
def search_image(self, image, confidence=.6, click=True):
location = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(image, confidence=confidence)
if location is not None:
    if click:
        pyautogui.click(location)
    return location
else:
    return False
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
import functions

functions.search_image('...')
```

Comment: I tested it just a moment ago. You have no whitespace between `import` and `*`